# How to prove that $\mathrm{T^1}\mathbb{H} \cong\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, manifolds, dynamical-systems, group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry

**Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory**, Chapter **9**, Page **281**.

> **Lemma 9.2.** *The action of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathrm{T}^1\mathbb{H}$ is simply transitive.*
>
> Notice that this allows us to describe the unit tangent bundle to $\mathbb{H}$ as
> $$\mathrm{T}^1\mathbb{H}\cong\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R}).\tag{9.4}$$
>
> In order to do this, we have to choose an arbitrary reference vector $(z_0,v_0)$ in $\mathrm{T}^1\mathbb{H}$ which corresponds to $I_2\in\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$; the identification is then given by $g\mapsto\mathrm{D}g(z_0,v_0)$. We will make the convenient choice $z_0=\mathrm{i}$ and $v_0=\mathrm{i}$. That is, the reference vector is the upward unit vector based at the imaginary unit $\mathrm{i}\in\mathbb{H}$. Under the resulting identification the action of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{H}$ is conjugated to the action of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ by left multiplication on $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

How do we have that $$\mathrm{T^1}\mathbb{H} \cong\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$$
And the last three lines in the attached image above (Under the resulting......$\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$).

Comment: What is the question exactly? $PSL_2(\Bbb{R})$ acts transitively on $\Bbb{H}$ and the stabilizer of $i$ is $PSO_2(\Bbb{R})$, which is acting transitively and freely on $(T_i \Bbb{H}-0)/\Bbb{R}^*$. Thus the action of $PSL_2(\Bbb{R})$ on $(T \Bbb{H}-0)/\Bbb{R}^*$ is transitive and free.

Comment: @reuns the question is that how to prove that $\mathrm{T^1}\mathbb{H} \cong\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and what do they mean by the last three lines?

Comment: I don't know what is $T^1$, I just proved the $\cong$

Comment: @reuns  $\mathrm{T^1}\mathbb{H} $ is the unit tangent bundle of $\mathbb{H}$. How did you prove the $\cong$? (I did not get your point).

Comment: Which step is unclear to you? With unit you mean unit norm in the hyperbolic metric? If so it follows from what I wrote and that the Möbius transformations are isometries.

Comment: @reuns Do you mean it is a result of orbit - stabiliser theorem?

Comment: If you want but we don't need any theorem. By the way above I meant $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$ not $\Bbb{R}^*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Iwasawa decomposition $SL_2\mathbb{R}=KAN$, where $K=SO(2)$, $A$ consists of diagonal elements, and $N$ consists of unitriangular elements, we can show $SL_2\mathbb{R}$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{H}$. Indeed, the subgroup $AN$ itself (upper triangular elements) acts transitively: you can use $a\in A$ to make the imaginary part of a point whatever you need it to be, then use $n\in N$ to make the real part whatever you want it to be.

Indeed, given any $(z,v)$ (with $v$ the unit tangent vector), you can use $g\in G$ to turn this into $(i,w)$ for some tangent vector $w$. Then, you can pick a $k\in K=SO(2)=\mathrm{Stab}(i)$ to apply to get $(i,i)$. Thus you can get $(i,i)$ from any $(z,v)$ (and thus also conversely).

The orbit-stabilizer theorem says if $G\curvearrowright\Omega$ is transitive then $\Omega\cong G/\mathrm{Stab}(\omega)$. In the case of a sharply transitive action (i.e. a regular action), this means $\Omega\cong G$ are equivalent $G$-sets. Picking the correspondence between $G$ and $\Omega$ amounts to picking a $\omega\in\Omega$ to correspond to $e\in G$. (In the case of $G$ a vector space and $\Omega$ an affine space, this means picking an "origin.") Then $g\mapsto g\omega$ is the equivalence $G\cong\Omega$. We have $G$ acting on itself by left-multiplication, of course.

Your source is choosing $\omega=(z_0,v_0)$ as a "reference vector" - specifically $(i,i)$ is nice.